# jQuery: how to display first element of an array without using each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jQuery function:

```
function(person){

$.each(person.return.high, function(key, value){
    document.write(value+"<br />"); 
});

}
```

Above function prints 4 values out of which I am looking for only initial i.e. 0th value. So in this case I won't need each loop.

**Edit**

This is the output:

```
value:44749
value_int:447499
display:440  
display_short:44
```

**Edit ends here**

But I am not getting how to do this.

I tried to do this:

```
var obj = person.return.high
document.write(obj[0])
```

But it gives "undefined" error.

Can anybody help me in making this work?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `person.return.high`?

Comment: `console.log(person.return.high)` https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni it is JSON data

Comment: It seems like it's not a JSON array, could you show us a simplified version of it?

Comment: Youu can check what are the indexes of the array by printing key in .each.
And then do obj.keyName where keyName is the first key printed in the .each loop.

Comment: What Json value does person.return.high contain?

Comment: wrote the output in edit in question @AlbertoZaccagni

Comment: tried this : document.write(obj['value'])

Comment: @user2206724, we need to know what `person` looks like, the format of the object formed from your JSON.

Comment: Maybe try document.write(obj["value"])

Comment: @Ramesh Hey thanks. Your solution worked! I was doing obj[value].. stupidity.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in person.return.high) {
 console.log(person.return.high[key]); 
 break; 
}
```